# Visual c++ resource files symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resources

I'm a little bit confused about Visual Studio (2013) resource files. I added a new bitmap to my project, it has it's own symbol, IDB_BITMAP1, though I'm not sure how to use it in MAKEINTRESOURCE macro. I have to use its number id, 101. I opened resource.h file with notepad and there is no #define directive for that. Do I have to manually add constants for my resource files or does VS do it automatically for me and I just miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I realized now, that adding a file doesn't modify resource.h file. I had to include it, use file's id in MAKEINTRESOURCE and just hit compile button, then it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical way of doing it:

Header file:

```
// resources.h
#ifndef _RESOURCES_H
#define _RESOURCES_H

#define IDB_BITMAP1 101

#endif
```

Resources file:

```
// resources.o
IDB_BITMAP1 BITMAP DISCARDABLE ".\myPic.bmp"
```

Source-code:

```
// other_file.cpp
#include "resources.h"
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(
    hInstance,
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP1),
    IMAGE_BITMAP,
    0,
    0,
    LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

Don't forget to release the memory, by doing

```
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
```

when the bitmap is no longer used.

Comment: I know how to do it by hand, but I'm confused if VS does it automatically for me, or do I have to keep track of all of my files.

Comment: If you can't find a #define IDB_BITMAP1 anywhere, your compiler should complain when you try to compile? That the compiler can't resolve what IDB_BITMAP1 is? Then you will need to define it yourself in a header file and include it.

Comment: Thank you, my compiler can't find that name, but I thought I have to maybe include something. VS uses some strange .aps files. Thanks again.